# How to apply contract behavior to service with an attribute?

Tags: c#, wcf, attributes

I've done everything like in example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.icontractbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx

But my `TestContractBehaviorAttribute` methods never gets called:

Here's an attribute where I've put breakpoints:

```
public class TestContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }
}
```

Contract and a service tagged with an attribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

[TestContractBehavior]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

After client's call `GetData` is executed but behavior attribute methods are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a new WCF Service project inside Visual Studio and added TestContractBehavior as you outlined to the default Service1 class.

The IContractBehavior methods get called during startup/hosting of the service. Calls to GetData do not hit any of them. These are startup methods.

To debug startup methods you can add `Debugger.Launch();` in service constructor, for example.